# Completly exclude all the PO Box variations for the shipping in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I use this function in woocommerce to block people from entering a pobox address. It work well, but it dosen't take into consideration people who enter other variations like 'po' or 'box'.

How can I make sure to block this also?

Thanks

```
/**
 * Prevent PO box shipping
 */
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'deny_pobox_postcode');

function deny_pobox_postcode( $posted ) {
  global $woocommerce;

  $address  = ( isset( $posted['shipping_address_1'] ) ) ? $posted['shipping_address_1'] : $posted['billing_address_1'];
  $postcode = ( isset( $posted['shipping_postcode'] ) ) ? $posted['shipping_postcode'] : $posted['billing_postcode'];

  $replace  = array(" ", ".", ",");
  $address  = strtolower( str_replace( $replace, '', $address ) );
  $postcode = strtolower( str_replace( $replace, '', $postcode ) );

  if ( strstr( $address, 'pobox' ) || strstr( $postcode, 'box' ) ) {
    wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( "Sorry, we cannot ship to PO BOX addresses.") ) ,'error' );
  }


}
```

Comment: What if someone happens to live on "72 Box Street, Greenpoint • Brooklyn NY 11222"? I would suggest to never filter addresses like this, just put a clear warning somewhere that you cannot deliver to PO BOX addresses.

Comment: I agree with the above comment. You can use a regular expression to match strings like pobox, box etc.

Comment: You are right, I didn't think about that. How can I do it with regex?

Comment: @OliverBigras-Morin posted an answer, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

Regex for looking for PO BOX: `/(PO|BOX)|PO?\s?BOX/gmi`

Explained:

- `/(PO|BOX)` string contains PO or BOX
- `|` or
- `PO?\s?BOX` PO followed by an optional space followed by BOX
- `/gmi` case global, multi line, case insensitive

Performing a regex in your code:

```
preg_match('/(PO|BOX)|PO?\s?BOX/gmi', $postcode, $matches);
if ($matches) {
    // you found a match! handle logic here
}
```

Obviously, be careful when using this regex as many other postcodes may legitimately contain 'PO' or 'BOX', so adapt this to your needs and research.

You can check it out here: https://regex101.com/r/d2PA4A/1

Comment: Thank you for the help. What does /gmi mean? I get an error in my log: PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: the `g` means globally, you can try taking it off as it was necessary when checking the regexes over several lines in the online editor.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I updated my function for this below.

The only down side is that the regex dosen't block 'po 123'

```
/**
 * Prevent PO box shipping
 */
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'deny_pobox_postcode');

function deny_pobox_postcode( $posted ) {
  global $woocommerce;

  $address  = ( isset( $posted['shipping_address_1'] ) ) ? $posted['shipping_address_1'] : $posted['billing_address_1'];
  $postcode = ( isset( $posted['shipping_postcode'] ) ) ? $posted['shipping_postcode'] : $posted['billing_postcode'];

  $replace  = array(" ", ".", ",");
  $address  = strtolower( str_replace( $replace, '', $address ) );
  $postcode = strtolower( str_replace( $replace, '', $postcode ) );

preg_match('/(?:P(?:ost(?:al)?)?[\.\-\s]*(?:(?:O(?:ffice)?[\.\-\s]*)?B(?:ox|in|\b|\d)|o(?:ffice|\b)(?:[-\s]*\d)|code)|box[-\s\b]*\d)/i', $address, $matches);
if ($matches) {
    wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( "Sorry, we cannot ship to PO BOX addresses.") ) ,'error' );
}

}
```